# Extension Development Case Requirement

Tags: extensions

I am trying to learn extension development using the official guide and I am confused with the use of different cases for naming different files and folders.

For instance, the proposed structure for the extension has been shown as:
[image]

What I notice is that the folders for Blocks, Models and Helpers are named starting with a Capital letter but the folders data, etc, sql and controller begin with small letters.

I find this inconsistency uncomfortable.

Further down the book, a file is named `Magentostudy_news.xml` but is then later referenced in `config.xml` as :

```
<layout>
  <updates>
    <magentostudy_news>
      <file>magentostudy_news.xml</file>
    </magentostudy_news>
  </updates>
</layout>
```

Note the inconsistency in file name capitalization.

I read that Magento favors configuration over convention but this inconsistency is kind of unnerving.

My question is this :
Can I have arbitary names, say use `Controller` instead of `controller` for sake of consistency ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento takes serious care on naming file/folder structures. What you have mentioned above is fully correct and unfortunately you cannot change them.

As I understand anything inside `design` folder should be small letters. So `Magentostudy_news.xml` should be `magentostudy_news.xml`, not sure if it works with `capital`. I always use small letters for these design files/folders.

Check [this](http://prattski.com/2012/10/30/magento-dev-best-practices-module-naming-conventions/).

Comment: `Magentostudy_news.xml` might not show error in Windows environment, but will definitely not work on Linux. Windows is sometimes soft on capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

First of all Magento following mvc structure. You have to follow extension developement structure in order to create extention.

**Steps**

1. create module configuration file inside

app/etc/nameofextesion.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Connect>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>core</codePool>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

2. Create local folder inside app folder
   app/local
3. Create folder package of your extension (i.e yourname or xyzcompany)
   app/local/Asoft
4. Create folder of your extension that you want to built. I want to create customer checkout extension

app/local/Asoft/Checkout

Here you need to create 6 folder

4.1
    app/local/Asoft/Checkout/Block

In block folder you will have to write business logic which is required to view pages

4.2

```
app/local/Asoft/Checkout/controllers
```

In controller folder you will have to write action login of your extension

4.3
    app/local/Asoft/Checkout/Helper

In Helper folder you will have to write general function

4.4

```
app/local/Asoft/Checkout/Model
```

In model folder you will have to write model which is used to take and give data from your app to db and vice versa

4.5
    app/local/Asoft/Checkout/Sql

In sql folder you will have to write db creation script to install script of your db table

4.6

```
app/local/Asoft/Checkout/etc
```

In config folder you will have to create config.xml file which is used to configure your extension

5. Or if you want to create layout, you will need to make layout's xml file which you had specified in config.xml

If it is admin related layout then you have to create inside design/adminhtml/default/default/layout

If it is front related layout then you have to create inside design/frontend/default/default/layout